# Finding a number greater than x in a range

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem which after some modifications reduces to "Finding the least index of number greater than x in a range[l, r] "

For example: Suppose an array `A = {1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 2}`

And the query is "**find least index of element in array A in range [2, 6] which is greater or equal to 5**"

Answer for the above query is 4(value for this index is 6)(Indices are 1 based)

There are multiple queries, array is not sorted(consider that input is already in memory)

Is there an algorithm in which query is possible in O(logN) where N is no. of elements in array A.

Comment: If the range [a,b] contains natural numbers a <= n <= b in sorted order, then you solve this in O(log N) for N= #elements using binary search.

Comment: You can do it in O((logN)^2).
Build a segment tree of your elements that can get a max in a range. Then do a binary search over your [A,B] range where you try to find the smallest index >= A where the max element in the range [A,index] is >= q. Use the segment tree to get this max in the range [A,index]. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Ghooo It looks like a correct solution for this problem. I doubt that we can perform each query in `O(logN)` in online.

Comment: @ghoo, building a segment tree takes O(N log N), which ends up as the complexity of your solution.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin that is correct. The overall time complexity will 
O(N Log N + M Log^2 N) where M is the number of queries. The space complexity will be O(N Log N). 

Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Ghooo, your comment also highlights a problem in the original question, where we don't know the relationship of the number of queries M versus the number of elements N, (and also as per my answer the total number of possible keys K).  For example, if we know that M will typically be larger than M, ordering the data g at a cost of n Log n makes sense, whereas if it will typically be smaller, it is not beneficial.

Comment: You can do queries in O(log N) if you first build a data structure that takes O(N) extra space and O(N) time to build. Let me know if that's acceptable and I'll write it out tonight.

Comment: @Ghooo Can you please explain your approach in detail. I am not quite getting the binary search part in a range.

Comment: @MattTimmermans That is acceptable. Please write the answer.

Comment: @Ghooo Got your point. I guess that would be correct and fairly optimal solution.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, can you explain how your structure take O(N) space and O(N) time please?  AFAIK, any tree will take O(N) space and O(N log N) time.  If a bucket sort / counting sort / pigeon hole sort approach is feasible for the data, it takes O(K) space and O(N) time to build, where K is the maximum number of possible keys.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin  You can easily build a binary tree from the bottom up in O(N) time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually a bunch of ways to support queries in O(log N) time after building a data structure that takes O(N) space.

## Easy to understand answer

- Make a binary tree with the elements of A as the leaves, ordered by index.
- In each internal node, record the maximum value of leaves in its subtree
- You need to be able to find the path to a node given its index. If necessary, record the index of the first leaf in each internal node.  You can get away without this by building your tree with a convenient shape.
- Now, to find the least index >= L with a value >= X:

  - Find the path in the tree to A[L]
  - If A[L] < X, then go up the tree until you find a right uncle that contains a value >= X
  - Go down the uncle tree to find the first leaf with value >=X.  While descending, if the left child has a leaf >= X (check the stored max value), then go left.  Otherwise go right.

## Super-Efficient Answer

To make the above algorithm really efficient, you can encode the tree into an array, like we do for heaps.  In this representation (using 1-based indexes), you have an array containing the maximum values for N-1 internal nodes, followed by the N leaves in order.  Call that array `H`.  Then the children of `H[i]` are at `H[i*2]` and `H[i*2+1]`.  The parent of `H[i]` is at `H[i>>1]`

In pseudocode, using 1-based indexes, we are given:

```
A[] = input array, N = input array size
```

We build H like this:

```
H = new array with size N*2-1, indexed from 1 to N*2-1
for (int i=1; i<=N; ++i)
    H[i+N-1]=A[i];
for (int i=N-1; i>0; --i)
    H[i] = max(H[2*i],H[2*i+1]);
```

Note that we create the children before the parents so that the children are there when we need to get the maximum of their values.

Now, the query function:

```
//get the index of the first element with val >= minval, index >= minindex, and index <= maxindex
//returns -1 if there is no such element

firstAtLeast(minval, minindex, maxindex)

    if (maxindex < minindex)
        return -1;

    node = minindex+N-1; //find minindex in the tree

    //go up and right until we find a subtree that has a value >= minval

    while(H[node] < minval)

        //if we are a right child of our parent, go up until
        //we have a right sibling
        while( (node&1) == 1 ) //node is odd
            node = node>>1;    //same as floor(node/2);
            if (node <= 1)
                //we went up to the root
                //there is no such element
                return -1;

        //now node is a left child.  try its right sibling        
        ++node;

    //We found a subtree.  get the first valid leaf

    while(node < N) //while it's an internal node
       node = 2*node; //left child of the node
       if (H[node] < minval)
           ++node;  //left child not valid - move to right child

    //Found leaf.  get index in A[i] and check against maxindex

    index = node-(N-1);
    return (index <= maxindex ? index : -1);
```

This satisfies the requirement for queries in O(log N) time.  It would be nice (and not too difficult) to exit early when you know there won't be an answer less than `maxindex`, but that would make the pseudocode a little less clear, so I'll leave it as an exercise

Comment: Once you make a binary tree, that takes a time of O(N log N) as opposed to the O(N) you mention in your original comment to the OP.

Comment: It only takes O(N) to make a binary tree.  You don't have to build it by repeated insertions

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin explaining how to build a tree in O(N), when you already know the ordering, doesn't fit in a comment.  If you want to open a question on it, I'll answer

Comment: Ok, ya got me, please show and tell; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852097/how-to-build-a-binary-tree-in-on-time

Comment: also please not the opening question states the data is unsorted.

Comment: It doesn't have to be sorted.  We want the tree to keep it in *index* order

Answer (score 4):

*O(logN)* seams to be impossible. You need at least to read the input until the first element which is greater (this might be the last one or none at all). So in the worst case you need to read the whole input which means **O(N)**.

Improvements are only possible if there is some extra structure of your input like *sorted* than you could improve the algorithm to *O(logN)*.

If there are multible queries you still need *O(logN)*. You can check for multible queries at once and also cache the results for the case that the same queries comes again.

Comment: Edited the question. Input is in memory. And there are multiple queries for different ranges and different search value.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of possible elements is small (say K) and can be readily enumerated, for an array of N elements, you can sort them in order N+K using a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).  You can then use a binary search for your query, which will be order log N.  Note the counting sort will also require order K memory, and hence is only useful where a relatively small number of discrete keys are in play.  If you have Q queries, the complexity is O((N+K) + Q(log(N))

Comment: Can you explain how to perform each query after sorting?

Comment: Given low end of range L, and high end of range H, search for L, adding one indexed position if nearest is <L, call the result IL.  Search for H subtracting one if indexed position >H, call the result IH.  If IL <= IH return IL otherwise return not found.  Note this is 2 log N which is also O(log N).

Comment: I didn't get your previous comment, after sorting using counting sort, how are you using binary search.

Comment: Once your data is sorted, if you search for the low and high elements in your range, adjusting up or down one to make sure the elements found are within your range, if the low element index is less than or equal to the high element index, the low element index is the item you're looking for.  If the low element index is greater than the high element index, there isn't any element in the range being sought.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of queries, with a moderate amount of data, you may be able to get a decent speed-up on your queries by O(N) extra storage.

Create an aray of tuples `(a[i], i)` (that is, value in the array, index of that value), sorted by the first (and in cases of conflict, the second) in ascending order. Then, use binary search to find your starting point. If the index is outside your range, continue to traverse your sorted list, until you find an index that falls within your range of interest.

I suspect this algorithm is O(N), worst case, so I guess it is possible to do better.