# How to build a binary tree in O(N ) time?

Tags: algorithm

Following on from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842055/finding-a-number-greater-than-x-in-a-range/35848683?noredirect=1#comment59367277_35848683) I'm keen to know how to build a binary tree from an array of N unsorted large integers in order N time?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck finding out. Did you have a question?

Comment: As far as I know, that's impossible, since it would imply you can sort a list in O(n) time.

Comment: Yes.  How do you build a binary tree from unsorted integers in O(n) time?

Comment: @MarcB Click the link for context.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, that's what I thought, but rather than say it can't be done, I'm always ready to listen and learn ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure that O(N * log(N)) is the best you can do.

Comment: @dboals: there is definitely a proof that you can *sort* a list of ints in no less than O(n).

Comment: But the link says "how to build a tree in O(N), when you already know the ordering". Which is different from building one from unsorted integers.

Comment: You can sort in O(n + k) for n items out of k possible variations using a bucket sort or counting sort.  Also uses O(k) space which can be prohibitively expensive (hence why I added large integers to the question above)

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin, yes, you can sort them in O(n+k) where k is the max difference between integers we are sorting. I too would think it is impossible to build BST in linear time in general.

Comment: @peppe, the opening question in the link explicitly talks about an unsorted array, and the original comments refer to that.  Saying we can sort in O(N) based on the assumption that the data is already sorted is kind of cheating, no?

Comment: There is no information that the tree is a search tree. In this you can insert in the order that you read the data - the tree will become a list in fact and the complexity will be O(N)

Comment: In the previous question referred to, the tree is in the original index order, not value order, so the input array is already sorted appropriately

Comment: Is it a binary tree or BST (Binary **search** tree)? The former can be easily built in O(n) time, and in fact - your array is a binary tree, where `arr[i].left = arr[i+1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just for completeness...  The binary tree in question is built from an array and has a leaf for every array element.  It keeps them in their original **index** order, **not value** order, so it doesn't magically let you sort a list in linear time.  It also needs to be balanced.

To build such a tree in linear time, you can use a simple recursive algorithm like this (using 0-based indexes):

```
//build a tree of elements [start, end) in array
//precondition: end > start
buildTree(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    if (end-start > 1)
    {
        int mid = (start+end)>>1;
        left = buildTree(array, start, mid);
        right = buildTree(array, mid, end);
        return new InternalNode(left,right); 
    }
    else
    {
        return new LeafNode(array[start]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my misinterpretation of not needing a sorted tree.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: I reformatted caps into boldface, since caps is (at least on SO) considered to be rude.

Comment: An array of input(doesn't matter if it is sorted or not) can be considered as complete binary tree and where the array can be assumed its level order traversal serialized form, based on this fact we can build a tree just by unwinding the level order traversal, atmost each element will be accessed twice when recursing back to root at each stage, so time complexity is O(2n) which is O(n). This property is exploited by Heaps in general which is a complete binary Tree.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some pre-conditions on the list that allow you to calculate the position in the tree for each item in constant time it is not possible to 'build', that is sequentially insert, items into a tree in O(N) time. Each insertion has to compare up to Log M times where M is the number of items already in the tree.

Comment: That was always my understanding, hence the question.  That said, just because we haven't seen the algorithm doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Binary search trees are one of the most studied topics in Computer Science. They are founded on the principals of sorting by comparison. It has been proven that the fastest comparison based insertion for BST is O(log n). To get any faster than that, you need some pre-existing structure in your dataset. For example if you knew your dataset was already sorted you could come up with a much quicker way to build the tree.

Comment: @user2313300 true, but that would imply being able to solve `SORT` in O(n), that has been proved impossible.

Comment: @JuanLopes I was not trying to imply sorting in O(n) time is possible, instead I was trying to exemplify if you were, say, given a dataset that you knew was already sorted.

Comment: @user2313300 You are right, I didn't even intended to reply to your comment, but Shane's one. But you are both right.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this seems impossible in general (assuming we have a general, totally ordered set *S* of *N* items.) Below is an informal argument where I essentially reduce the building of a BST on *S* to the problem of sorting *S*.

*Informal argument.* Let *S* be a set of *N* elements. Now construct a binary search tree *T* that stores items from *S* in *O(N)* time.

Now do an inorder walk of the tree and print values of the leaves as you visit them. You essentially sorted the elements from *S*. This took you *O(|T|)* steps, where *|T|* is the size of the tree (i.e. the number of nodes). (The size of the BST is *O(N log N)* in the worst case.)

If *|T|=o(N log N)* then you just solved the general sorting problem in *o(N log N)* time which is a contradiction.

Comment: I agree it is impossible in general where there are a huge number of possible values for the items being sorted.  Where there are a small number of possible values for the items being sorted, and these values can be enumerated, we can sort in O(N) using something like a counting sort, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort  If we can sort in this case in O(n) I'd guess we could also construct a tree.

Comment: **If** you are given a sorted array, then you may be able to construct a binary search tree in linear time, yes, but only if the representation is such that it takes *O(N)* space (i.e. you use an array similar to the way you do with heaps). I thought the question was whether this is possible in general.

Comment: Vague idea: 1. sort  the array; 2. put the middle element of the sorted array in the root; 3. recurse on the subarrays (first and last halves), i.e. put their roots as second and third elements of the arrat respectively. (The left child of element at index i is at 2*i; the right child is at 2*i+1.)

Comment: also my understanding of things.  The question was a bit of a reality to check to see if there had been some huge leap forward in algorithmics since I last leafed through by ageing copy of Knuth.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin, I see. I am now sure I can build a BST in O(N) time (and obviously O(N) space) given a sorted arraty of size N. Have to think out the detials though.

Comment: see my comment on Matt Timmermans answer.  Given the tree structure ends up having n log n nodes, I think at best you can achieve O(N + log(N)) complexity.  Basically, you need to pre-allocate all your nodes, and assign their links in a fixed number of passes.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, how it is possible.

Sort array with RadixSort, this is O(N). Thereafter, use recursive procedure to insert into leafs, like:

```
node *insert(int *array, int size) {
  if(size <= 0)
     return NULL;
  node *rc = new node;
  int midpoint = size / 2;
  rc->data = array[midpoint];
  rc->left  = insert(array, midpoint);
  rc->right = insert(array + midpoint + 1, size - midpoint - 1);
  return rc;
}
```

Since we do not iterate tree from up to down, but always attach nodes to a current leafs, this is also O(1).

Comment: You cannot use RadixSort in O(N) if you don't have an upper bound on the integers.